# How do I mark the vertices and add the x and y values to the coordinates?

Tags: matplotlib, vertices

[image]
If I plot the graph with matplotlib, how do I mark the vertices and add the x and y values to the coordinates?
My code is as follows. Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def f(x):[![enter image description here][1]][1]
     return x ** 2
If __name__ == '__main__':
     x = np.arange(-2, 2, 0.1)
     y = f(x)
     plt.plot(x, y, label='f(x)')
     plt.legend()
     plt.show()
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean x and y labels?

You can do:

`plt.xlabel('xlabel')
 plt.ylabel('ylabel')`

To label that specific point, you can try:

`plt.annotate('label', xy=(x, y) )`

Comment: Thank you for your advice, this is indeed the feature I want.